# Video textures in imported 3D models in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

I would like to know if it's possible to use video textures in imported models in A-Frame and how I would go about doing that. I am trying to import obj or COLLADA models from Blender with video textures but I can't figure out how to do it.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OBJ and COLLADA model formats do not support video textures. I'm not aware of any common format that does. You would need to load the model and the video separately, perhaps applying the video to the model with something like https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-video-shader.